# Jquery Wordpress Animation

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm currently doing a project of uploading diary entries of a trip to wordpress.

I'm wondering if there is a way with jQuery/JavaScript/php to have a timeline where an image of a boat moves across a timeline depending on which posts you are reading.

For example, say there are 90 posts and post one was the start point, posts two would move the image of the boat a little forward, on the other end if your at posts 90 then the boat would be at the end of the timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need two important pieces of information: the total number of posts, and the position of the current post in the order. That second one could be trickier. Maybe query the database to get the count of posts before or after the current one and subtract from the total.

With those bits of info in hand, scale them to a 0 - 100 percentage value:

```
$precent = ($position / $totalCount) * 100;
```

then your css and html might look something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #boat-progress { position:relative;height:40px;margin-right:100px;overflow:visible; }
    #boat-progress img { position:absolute;top:0;left:0; }
</style>
<div id="boat-progress">
    <img src="boat.png" alt="Boat" style="left:<?php=$percent ?>%;" />
</div>
```

I put that "margin-right" on there because when the image is at 100%, it will actually be off the right edge. The 100px is guessing at an image that might be 100px wide. By offsetting the parent div to allow for that space, it should work. It's a pretty quick and dirty solution, though.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give this a crack with maybe the animate function of jquery. Cheers, thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty involved question, best to break it into parts. Here is a pretty high-level description of what would need to be done.

In order to animate between two points representing pages, you'll need knowledge of which page the user was previously on. You can perhaps do this by storing the current page in the user's session, or perhaps by looking at the HTTP referrer.

Once you have that information, its just a matter of animating between the previous page's position on the timeline and the current one. jquery makes this easy.

$('#boat').animate({'left','100px');

You'll need to know how far apart your markers are (maybe 5 px per page), and to position the boat on the previous page's marker when the page loads (do this with PHP, since PHP has knowledge of the previous page). Then when the page loads use the above js to transition to the new position.

Comment: would the following work $('#boat').animate({'left','<?php=$percent ?>%');

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely be a custom solution you would have to do and not so much a question that has a basic answer here.

However, if it helps at all you could start by categorizing the posts in a common way - or tagging them. WP allows both. Since we don't know how you're using the site let's just go with tags.

I don't think I have time to write out the full WP syntax here, especially since they have documentation that's easy to follow. Here's the basic idea though -

on page load, get the posts with the common tag then run the loop...

```
$total = 0;
$position = 0;
$i = 0;
$this_id = $whatever_current_id_is;
while($the_tag_result_loop)
{
    $total ++;
    $the_id = get_the_ID();
    if($this_id == $the_id)
    {
        $position = $i;
    }
    $i ++;
}
```

Then at the end of this horribly inefficient loop you can divide your timeline area by the $total var to get the amount of space each page should represent. Let's say your screen area or "lake" is 1000 pixels wide.

```
$each_gets = 1000 / $total;
```

Then multiply your $position var by the $each_gets to find your left margin.

```
$left_margin = $each_gets * $position;
```

Then of course apply this to the element in question.

```
<div id="boat" style="margin-left:<?php echo $left_margin; ?>px"></div>
```

Keep in mind this is not intended to be a copy / paste solution or anything. It's just a point in A direction, not necessarily the best direction.

Personally I would write a WP plugin to compose this on article submit and write the results into the post itself. That wouldn't be particularly difficult, but definitely not something I feel like writing out here.